# Circle not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to detect a circle from  a given image. But it just doesn't work the way I want it to. I implemented a circle detection algorithm, which works on some images with a circle but not on the one I want. I tweaked with the parameters, but couldn't get it  to work.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load the image, clone it for output, and then convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread("damn-circle.png")
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# detect circles in the image
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 120)
cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([blur]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
print circles

# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Normal circle]
[image: The circle I want to detect]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is almost perfect. It's just that the method `CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT` sits inside a package, `cv` (at least for opencv version: 2.4.13). I changed that one line to mention the package and it worked well. You'll have to put specific versions for OpenCV and NumPy if you're still not getting the right result on this simple image. Change your line to be like this:

`circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 120)`
 You should get a nice result. At least I just did. [image with found Hough circle shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X08bc.png)

Edited:
Ah, I didn't understand which image the question was about. I changed parameters for several items particularly the Canny detector param and the radius min/max and the accumulator resolution. I think these params will find what you want:

`circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, method = cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, minDist = 90 , dp = 1, param1 = 3, param2 = 12 , minRadius = 30, maxRadius = 50)`

My found image now looks like this: [another image with found circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39W9Y.png)

Comment: You maybe misunderstood me. I am using OpenCV 3.0. The package `cv2.cv` moved just to `cv2`. I can perfectly detect the image you could too, but try the same code with the image below. It is not working :)

Comment: I edited my answer to cover the image you wanted to find the circle in.